# Why is the CAFCI breaker for my pool motor tripping?

Tags: wiring, circuit-breaker, motor

I’m having a problem with my 20 amp CAFCI breaker constantly tripping. The only device on it is my 1 1/2 horsepower pool motor. I have been using this motor for two years and just like that the breaker started tripping.

Sometimes the pump will run two or three hours before tripping other times it will trip as soon as the pump turns on. I tested the breaker and it seems to be working ok. I also ran the pump motor on another outlet on a different circuit and it ran fine. I appreciate any help you can give.

---

The CAFCI was installed 13 years ago and never has it ever tripped until this summer, it ran my pool pump from the middle of April till July 5 when it started tripping. I had a 25 year old pump running on this circuit up until I replaced it 2 years ago and worked fine until now

Comment: When a CAFCI breaker starts tripping, the **first** thing to suspect is that there **is an arc fault**, not that there is some problem with the breaker. What is the make and model of the breaker? Does it give any diagnostics for **why** it tripped? Many do. Was the other circuit also CAFCI protected? Pleased [edit] the question to clarify.

Comment: Does a pool motor have to be on an AFCI? A pool motor is outside so if it overheated it would not start a fire in the structure. Wouldn't a GFCI be sufficient for a pool motor? Or is internal arcing unacceptable in any motor?

Comment: Yeah, there's no reason a pool motor needs to be on an AFCI -- if anything, it should be on a GFCI...

Comment: My read of 2020 code has pool motors only requiring GFCI. I bet this is an arc fault due to a motor problem or a loose connection. Swap the breaker for GFCI only, or replace the motor with one that doesn't fault.

Comment: Tell us where you live (city/state/country is sufficient) as code requirements vary. In the US, some places are still on NEC 2008 while others have already adopted 2020. The advice about switching to a GFCI may or may not apply to you based on your local laws. If you're _not_ in the US, then other (but similar) rules will apply.

Comment: Hi! You have a couple of unregistered accounts. Please consider [registering](/help/why-register) one of them, then [merge them](/help/merging-accounts) together, which will allow you to [edit](/help/privileges/create-posts) and [comment on](/help/privileges/comment) any of your posts and most importantly [accept an answer](/help/someone-answers). Thanks, and welcome to the site!

Answer (score 2):

Newer cAFCI breakers have a diagnostic feature the stores the reason for the most recent trip.  I would google the instructions of that model of breaker and get it to tell you whether we're dealing with a ground fault, arc fault, or overcurrent/short circuit.

Given that it's pool equipment handling water, I suspect a ground fault.  Most AFCIs, and all that take a neutral wire, have a weak GFCI functionality operating at 30mA threshold, not quite enough for human safety but enough to detect hot-ground and neutral-ground arc faults.

If you cordon off the pool for safety, you could swap in a plain breaker and then use a clamp ammeter to measure both hot and neutral wire together (but not ground).  They should read zero amps since magnetic fields of the two wires should be equal and opposite, so should cancel each other out.

If clamping hot and neutral shows a current, then clamp hot, neutral and ground together.  If that shows zero, then the ground fault is being caught by the grounding.  If it reads non-zero, the power is going somewhere else, and the pool is being energized right now!  Don't leave it like this - put it back on the AFCI right away.

Don't be tempted to run it without xFCI protection, and if you do, DO NOT jump in to rescue anyone in distress, until you turn off that breaker! "The first couple of rescuers also dying" happens a lot.